# Powershell unexpected token

Tags: powershell

have a great 2013. I am getting my hands wet on my first PS Script and I am stuck on a very common error, the "Unexpected Token" error. I've searched the internet, but could not find an answer, so please help me out.

```
    If ($_.Voorvoegsel.Trim() -ieq "") {
        $dn = $_.Voornaam.Trim() + " " 
        $dn += $_.Achternaam.Trim()
        $email = $_.Voornaam.substring(0,1).ToLower() + "."
        $email+= $_.Achternaam.Trim().ToLower() + "@test.nl
    } Else {
        $dn = $_.Voornaam.Trim() + " "
        $dn += $_.Voorvoegsel.Trim() + " "
        $dn += $_.Achternaam.Trim() 
        $email = $_.Voornaam.substring(0,1).ToLower() + "."
        $email += $_.Voorvoegsel.Replace(" ","").ToLower()
        $email += $_.Achternaam.Trim().ToLower() + "@test.nl
    }
```

The strange thing is that it errors on the $_.Voorvoegsel variable in the else statement:

```
Unexpected token '
            $dn += $_.Voorvoegsel.Trim()
            $dn += ' in expression or statement.
At C:\Users\Public\Documents\PSImportTest.ps1:42 char:12
+             $dn = $_ <<<< .Voornaam.Trim() + " "
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (
            $dn += $_....m()
            $dn += :String) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

Anyone out there who sees what my blind spot is here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be that you are missing an end quote on line 5:

```
$email += $_.Acternaam.Trim().ToLower() + "@test.nl"
```

It looks like you also may be missing one on line 12. Powershell may think the rest of the code, until the next quote character, is part of your string literal.

Comment: Thanks! Somehow I kept looking over this.